# How to view browser content on Linux with no GUI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have an AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, but only have access to the command line and not a GUI.

I need to open localhost and see if it is running and how it looks.

Is there some way to view the contents without a GUI interface?

Answer (score 3):

Use a text based browser like [links](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)), [w3m](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m), or [Elinks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks), or another text based browser... The ones mentioned above are part of the standard Ubuntu repository plus more if you search.

Comment: Also add [lynx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))

Comment: @Biswa I gave three common examples, I don't see it clarifying the answer to give more options... a quick Google search will come up with dozens more possibilities if the ones listed are not sufficient for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If this means that you have a web server installed and want to check if it serves a page, just use wget or curl:

```
wget http://localhost
```

To have the HTML printed directly on your terminal session, use:

```
wget -O - http://localhost
```